# ArUco Markers are not detected

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, aruco

I'm trying to detect the ArUco markers in this image:

[image: img]

using this code:

```py
import cv2
import cv2.aruco as aruco
import numpy as np

def findArucoMarkers(img, markerSize = 5, totalMarkers=250, draw=True):    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    key = getattr(aruco, f'DICT_{markerSize}X{markerSize}_{totalMarkers}')
    arucoDict = aruco.Dictionary_get(key)
    arucoParam = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
    bboxs, ids, rejected = aruco.detectMarkers(gray, arucoDict, parameters = arucoParam)
    print(ids)
    if draw:
        aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(img, bboxs)
    return [bboxs, ids]

path = ""
imName= "test3.png"

img = cv2.imread(path+imName)

arucofound = findArucoMarkers(img, markerSize = 5)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Sadly, no marker is detected! can you please tell me how can I detect the markers correctly? thanks in advance.

### Edit:

The markers are **5x5** generated online from this [website](https://chev.me/arucogen), the IDs: `0, 2, 4, 12, 17`

The camera used `Asus Xtion Live Pro`.

Comment: are you *sure* it's the 5X5 type, not some other type with 5x5 modules? there's some "classic" type.

Comment: @CristophRackwitz I'm pretty sure and tested the `findArucoMarkers` on the same marker on the video stream from my PC camera, it was working well!

Comment: why are the required quiet zones around those markers missing? _do not_ crop the white area around the markers. it's PART of the marker.

Comment: the rectangles [are detected](https://i.imgur.com/A12MxEZ.png), but they are rejected. please give exact details on what these markers are. IDs, types, etc. everything, to reproduce these markers.

Comment: ... did you MIRROR THE IMAGE? that marker in the middle has ID 17... I just flipped through the first 18 aruco markers and used my eyes to compare. why are the markers mirrored?

Comment: @CristophRackwitz "*did you MIRROR THE IMAGE?*" [The mirroring is happened by default in the video stream from Xtion Pro](https://answers.ros.org/question/200132/xtionopenni2-image-flipped/?answer=210208#post-id-210208) unless it is disabled!, thanks for your remark, I have edited the question with ArUco IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The picture is a mirror image of the markers.

ArUco markers will not be decoded when they're mirrored.

Prevent/undo the mirroring. Find the device/driver setting that does this.

`flipped = cv.flip(img, 1)` flips the image around the Y-axis.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the other way around is to disable the mirroring from the `OpenNi2` API using  `color_stream.set_mirroring_enabled(False)`, the same goes for the `depth_stream`.